# Avoid redundance with toCharArray() or arrayCopy within loop

Tags: java, arrays, time-complexity

I have made the following method which replaces each of the letters in a word wih all possible letters from the alphabet, and stores all the alternative words in an array:

```
private String[] replaceLetters(String word, char[] alphabet){
    //replacing one letter with an arbitrary letter from alphabet, for each letter place in the word.
    int wordLength = word.length();
    String[] words = new String[alphabet.length*wordLength];
    char[] tmpWord = word.toCharArray();
    int counter = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<wordLength; i++){
        tmpWord = word.toCharArray();   
        for(char c : alphabet){
            tmpWord[i] = c;
            words[counter] = new String(tmpWord);
            counter++;
        }
    }
    return words;
}
```

At the beginning of the for-loop I use String.toCharArray() to create a new object, so that the changes made to the tmpWord-object in the inner loop are reset. In other words, I want to make sure that tmpWord is reset so that it equals the original char array word.toCharArray() for each iteration in the loop.

It seems like repeating this operation for every iteration in the outer loop should be redundant. I know that the time complexity of toCharArray() is O(N), and since the outer loop is also O(N), it is my understanding that the time complexity of this snippet is O(N^2). Is there a more frictionless way of doing this?

Comment: `new String(tmpWord)` copies the array too.

Comment: But I still would need to have it converted to a charity array, so I am not sure it saves time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create `tmpWord` once, before the outer loop, and put the character you changed in the inner `for` loop back after making the new `String`, restoring `tmpWord` to its original contents.

Not sure how "frictionless" that is.

Comment: You'd probably want to store the original character in a variable to make it easy to put back, but this is pretty much the answer I was going to give.

Comment: Yes! That's exactly what i could not think of. This solution is both obvious and performs alot better. Thank you both!